# How is every finite linear combination of eigenstates of H a bound state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

[image: lin comb bound states]

This is all i could find in my lecture notes about this. Its not very useful tbh.
How can i show this?

Thanks

Comment: Your equations are not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a *linear combination* of bound states in QM, it means that a "measurement" will always give you an atom in *one of the states* $|n\rangle$ of this combination.